# linking 3rd party payees to paypal

Tags: javascript, java, html, paypal

I am trying to create a website that will allow people to post items for sale and then receive a payment through paypal once the item is purchased.  Ideally I would have them link their paypal account to my website, before they post any items, and user would checkout via paypal.  This would be a very similar setup to what ebay has with paypal.  Can someone point me to what type of integration this is?  Also could someone point me to the proper docs?  I don't think i'm using the correct terminology so I'm not finding anything.  I am a developer so i'm not afraid to code this up.  Thanks

Comment: Why is Java one of your tags?

Comment: This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create this kind of integration you will need to make a few user experience decisions first. The flow of Ebay allows a person to link a payment method to their system and upon purchase directs them to an Ebay paypal checkout page that acts as a payment using stored credentials to do a transaction with the Ebay paypal account. Internally Ebay then performs other transactions from their account with other user's registered payment information to mediate the exchange. It is not directly user-to-user. The first question you as a developer need to answer is : Do you want to use the pre-built paypal experience or design your own with paypal integration?

The simplest pre-built experience causes your users to be directed away from your website to paypal where they handle their transactions and then are returned to your site along with a REST payload that informs your site whether a transaction was successful or not.

Another service offered by paypal is called Paypal Payment Advance which allows them to provide you with a template integration on your website which performs the transactions on your domain. To learn more about that, see [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced).

The custom experience requires you to learn the Paypal developer API and how Paypal operates and stores credentials which can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/). This option is only if you really want to have complete control of everything and are willing to put in the work. It is also the most difficult option, but gives you the greatest control over the end experience.